# do shell script Sed and Perl: Using & as the matched string

Tags: perl, sed, applescript

input: `abc720p`

desired output: `abc720p_xxx`

follow the guide: [Using & as the matched string](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-3)

In AppleScript, If I use sed:

```
set oriT to "abc720p def720p" 
set oriT to do shell script "echo " & 
quoted form of oriT & " | sed -e 's/abc720p/&_xxx/g'"
```

the output is correct: `abc720p_xxx def720p`

But if I use Perl:

```
set oriT to "abc720p def720p" 
set oriT to do shell script "echo " &
quoted form of oriT & " | perl -CIOED -p -e 's/abc720p/&_xxx/g'"
```

the output is wrong: `&_xxx def720p`

In my context, I have to use Perl in AS to do this job (like & in sed).
I cannot use "perl -CIOED -p -e 's/abc720p/abc720p_xxx/g".

I don't know if I can achieve this with Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, the syntax is slightly different: use `$&` instead of `&`.

```
perl -CIOED -p -e 's/abc720p/$&_xxx/g'
```

See [$&](https://p3rl.org/perlvar#$&) for details.

Comment: One could also use `s/abc720p\K/_xxx/g`

Comment: I was surprised that worked since you didn't have to set off the `$&` from the immediately following identifier characters. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @briandfoy: I was surprised as well, but it's probably because `&` can't form a multicharacter identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! @choroba 's method works in my AS. `set oriT to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of oriT & " | perl -CIOED -p -e 's/abc720p/$&_xxx/g'"` -sucess. @ikegami 's method doesn't work in my AS. `set oriT to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of oriT & " | perl -CIOED -p -e 's/abc720p\K/_xxx/g'"` -failed. The compile error is "Expected “"” but found unknown token." and the character K is highlighted.

Comment: @CaiYu I'm guessing that the string literal `"...\K..."` doesn't produce the string `...\K...` in AS. You need to use a string literal that produces the correct string. I don't know AS, but you need to escape `\ ` in many languages

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler with AppleScript:

```
set oriT to "abc720p def720p"
set |&| to "abc720p"

set my text item delimiters to {|&| & "_xxx", |&|}

set oriT to text items of oriT as text
    --> "abc720p_xxx def720p"
```